# Why does not .setGeometry() change the size of an instance of QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to change QPushButton's size using QWidget's [.setGeometry(・・・)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setGeometry) function. I have the following code to try and change the size of the button.

```
import sys

from PyQt5           import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, method=-1):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(mainWidget)

        table = QTableWidget(10, 3)
        button = QPushButton("Why?")

        if   (method == 1):
            print("Method 1:", button.size(), end="")
            button.setMinimumSize(100, 100)
        elif (method == 2):
            print("Method 2:", button.size(), end="")
            button.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        else:
            print("Method X:", button.size(), end="")
        print(" -> ", button.size(), sep="")

        mainLayout.addWidget(table)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("python QLayoutGeometry.py[ <MethodToUse=-1>")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    method = -1 if (len(sys.argv) < 2) else int(sys.argv[1])
    GUI = Window(method)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However it does not seem to change the size of the button in **2.** when setGeometry(・・・) is used. My understanding, hence my expectation, must be wrong. Could someone clarify the part where I wrote "(**Not** what I expected)"

1. Executing `python QLayoutGeometry.py 1` calls `button.setMinimumSize(100, 100)`

   - Does change the size of the button (what I expected)
   - STDOUT shows: `Method 1: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480) -> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480)` (**Not** what I expected)
2. **Executing `python QLayoutGeometry.py 2` calls `button.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))`**

   - Does **not** change the size of the button (**Not** what I expected)
   - STDOUT shows: `Method 2: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480) -> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(100, 100)` (what I expected)
3. Executing `python QLayoutGeometry.py -1` does nothing

   - Does **not** change the size of the button (what I expected)
   - STDOUT shows: `Method X: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480) -> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480)` (what I expected)

Memo:

- [QPushButton's](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QPushButton.html) class hierarchy: ... QWidget -> QAbstractButton.
- [QWidget's size() function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop)

> The size is adjusted if it lies outside the range defined by minimumSize() and maximumSize().

Comment: I recommend that you read the [Layout Management article](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/overviews/layout.html) in the docs. For widget sizing, see the section [Adding Widgets to a Layout](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/overviews/layout.html#adding-widgets-to-a-layout). This will make it clear why `setGeometry` is somewhat redundant for widgets inside layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that layout managers, as the name suggests, *manage* the layout. It's their responsibility to position and resize the items contained in them and, eventually, request the widget on which they are set to expand its size.

Considering this, whenever a layout manager is set, calling `setGeometry` is almost useless, especially if done within the widget creation phase, and calling it even before adding the widgets to the layout is pointless for the same reason.

Then, the outputs you get are expected:

- by default, the initial size of a new widget that has not been shown yet is **always** 640x480 (or 100x30 for widget created with a parent);
- setting a minimum size doesn't alter the current (default) size of the widget *unless* the width or the height have bigger values;
- the *final* size of the widgets is not *readable* until the top level widget is finally shown and properly resized (if required) by the windowing system, *unless* the top level widget has been explicitly resized **and** the layout has been [`activated()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#activate);

The following will print the *correct* size even within the `__init__` (but you shouldn't do this for general usage, as `activate` is automatically called):

```
    mainLayout.addWidget(button)        
    mainLayout.activate()
    print(" -> ", button.size(), sep="")
```

That said:

- if you want to set a specific size for a widget, you must use `setFixedSize()`
- if a specific position or geometry is required, it must be done using a combination of `setFixedSize()` and eventually spacer items, layout margins, layout spacings and or strech factors;
- layout managers exist to *optimize* the available space, based on their size hints (both `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint`), size constraints and size policies, which are often computed based on system configuration (DPI, default font), so trying to set a fixed geometry is not only discouraged, but also possibly counterproductive: if you don't consider those aspects, you risk having widgets that become unusable or that overlap with others;

Finally, it *is* possible to call `setGeometry()`, but it can only be done *after* a resize event and after you're completely sure that the layout has done *its job*, which is something that is often unpredictable due to the complex nature of layouts and the possible existence of complex widgets (like scroll areas) that update their sizes in multiple passes; the general rule is that if you need to use `setGeometry` even when using layouts, then the layout (or the properties of its widgets) was not created/configured properly.

Comment: Calling `mainLayout.activate()` and then calling `button.size()` did indeed give the current size of the widget: `PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(75, 23)` in my environment. Thank you for making me move forward in my understanding.